# Uncaught ReferenceError:LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, uncaught-exception

i'm trying to understand the problem which i'm stucked  with.
I'm doing an application for Android through Cordova.
I looked for a solution but i haven't actually found it.

Firstly i had a problem with "requestFileSystem" that was not defined, but it seems to be fixed now.
Once i fixed that problem, the issue moved to another function.

I have basically a button which should create, save (and possibly show) a PDF:

```
<!--Button to generate PDF-->

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-mini="true">
            <h3>Reports</h3>

            <div>
                <a href="javascript:pdfCreation()" class="button"data-role="button" id="PageUnitButtonGeneratePDIReport">Generate PDI Report</a>
                <!--<iframe width="100%" height="500px" id="pdfOutContainer"></iframe>-->
            </div>

        </div>
```

And this is my JS code that contain the problem:

```
function pdfCreation() {

    //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT ON TABLET, DOESN'T SHOW
    console.log("generating pdf...");
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');
    doc.setFont("courier");
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
    doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');
    var pdfUriString = doc.output('datauristring');
    console.log(pdfUriString);
    var pdfOutContainer = jQuery("#pdfOutContainer");
    pdfOutContainer.attr("src", pdfUriString);

    //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
    console.log("file system...");
    //requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

        console.log(fileSystem.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

        fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
            var fileEntry = entry;
            console.log(entry);

            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                    console.log("write success");
                };

                console.log("writing to file");
                writer.write( pdfOutput );
            },

            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        },

        function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    },

    function(event){
        console.log( evt.target.error.code );
    });
}
```

The function which has the problem is pdfCreation.
I add the jdfiddle here, just in case it may be useful.

https://jsfiddle.net/antus2f0/

If anyone can help me out, would be nice!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up your code a bit. It was missing a `}`. Also if you're running the function in jsFiddle, you'll get a `is not defined` error on the function, because it's automatically wrapped inside a `window.onload` function.

Here's the working code:

```
window.pdfCreation = function() {

  //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT ON TABLET, DOESN'T SHOW
  console.log("generating pdf...");
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');
  doc.setFont("courier");
  doc.setFontType("normal");
  doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
  doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');
  var pdfUriString = doc.output('datauristring');
  console.log(pdfUriString);
  var pdfOutContainer = jQuery("#pdfOutContainer");
  pdfOutContainer.attr("src", pdfUriString);

  //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
  console.log("file system...");
  //requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

        console.log(fileSystem.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

        fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {
            create: true
          }, function(entry) {
            var fileEntry = entry;
            console.log(entry);

            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                  console.log("write success");
                };

                console.log("writing to file");
                writer.write(pdfOutput);
              },

              function(error) {
                console.log(error);
              });

          },

          function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      },
      function(event) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
The error that i have now is a little bit different, but i've already found it during several test i did.

"Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Working around the code I got the following working solution which can, hopefully, help someone else in the future.

```
window.pdfCreation = function() {

        //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
        console.log("generating pdf...");
        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.setFont("TimesNewRoman");   
        doc.text(20, 10, 'HELLO!');
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF summary.');    


        //PDF GENERATION ENDED

        var pdfOutput = doc.output();
        console.log( pdfOutput );

        //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
        console.log("file system...");
        alert("Creating PDF...Please wait a few seconds!");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

            console.log(fileSystem.name);
            console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
            console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

            fileSystem.root.getFile( $("#PageUnitPurchaserName").text() + $("#PageUnitUnitName").text() + ".pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {

                var fileEntry = entry;
                console.log(entry);

                entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                    console.log("write success");
                    alert("PDF successfully created!");
                };

                console.log("writing to file");
                    writer.write( pdfOutput );
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        },

        function(event){
            console.log( evt.target.error.code );
        });
    }
```